# Download multiple files from FTP in Matlab

Tags: matlab, ftp

I am trying to download some files from FTP and save on local folder.I tried this code but it does not work correctly.Anybody can help me??
Thank you in advance

```
ftp_client = ftp('n5eil01u.ecs.nsidc.org');
% ff=cd(ftp_client, '/pub/MOST/MOD10A1.005/2000.02.26');
m=dir(ftp_client, 'SAN/MOST/MOD10A1.005/2000.02.26/*.xml');
filename={m.name};
for k=1:length(filename)
    name =filename{k}(2:end-1)
    if isequal(name(19),'2')==1 && (isequal(name(20),'1')==1 || isequal(name(20),'2')==1 || isequal(name(20),'3')==1) && isequal(name(22),'0')==1 && (isequal(name(23),'5')==1 || isequal(name(23),'6')==1)
        mget(ftp_client, '*.xml', 'E:\myfolder')
    end
end
```

I get this message:

> "Undefined function or method 'mget' for input arguments of type 'cell'  "

I  want to loop over all  files and download specific files so add FOR to above code.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the documentation for `mget`. Filename is second and not first input parameter and you have to call `mget` for each file individually in a loop.